# SVN check if a particular directory got modified in repositry

Tags: svn

How we can check if a particular directory in the repository got modified i.e. some commit happened. As I want to put a mechanism for re-building only those directories which has some modification and not all.
I tried to use `svn info` but it didn't provide a way to get if there is any modification or not. Below is sample output

```
$svn info .
Path: .
Working Copy Root Path: /workspace/test
URL: https://<url>/Build
Relative URL: ^/<path>/Build
Repository Root: <url>
Repository UUID: ca5148ef-fb83-4fc3-a7e4-3a3ab6a18477
Revision: 8496
Node Kind: directory
Schedule: normal
Last Changed Author: test
Last Changed Rev: 8455
Last Changed Date: 2015-06-03 17:46:29 +0530 (Wed, 03 Jun 2015)
```

So if I ran `svn info` multiple time I am not able to figure out if there is modification as the revision is global revision number.
The use case for which this automation is required is that the build happens using bamboo.
So on day 1 if say the last changed rev is 10. But on 10th day how to find that still the directory has no commit so no re-build is required. We can't book keep the revision numbers.
So any thought how to get this information.

Answer (score 0):

Check 'Last Changed Rev:' in svn info output

Comment: Updated my question with use case.

Comment: As I understand (my english is not good) you can't keep last build revision number? Then you can't detect changes, because you can't detect changes since unknown moment. You need know either last revision or last date.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a working directory, you can use `svn status`:

```
 svn status -qu <your directory>
```

If there are modifications with respect to your working directory you will get a list of modified files/directories. Otherwise, no output is given.

Comment: The code will be check-out on a build server. So this command will not help as it will result into a re-build. As i have pre-build libraries which we want to reuse if no modification occur. But these libraries are not part of the repository. So it will be copied from some other place if no rebuild is required.

Comment: @Abhinav: What information can you use? Can you use a timestamp? In that case you can use `svn log` to find changes since a certain date/time: `svn log -q -r '{YY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss}:HEAD' <your dir>`.